# Is there a way to reference the variable being assigned to after the = in python? Similar to +=

Tags: python, python-3.x

Python has +=, -=, *=, %=, etc.  Is there a generic form of this?  The first thing I thought to try was:

```
x = _ + 1
```

as a generic version of `x+=1`.  I was curious about this as my actual code looks like this right now:

```
a = x[y][z]
x[y][z] = f(a)
```

and something like `x[y][z] = f( _ )` made sense in my head, maybe its something I just want to be there, but isn't.  Is there anything similar to this in Python?

Comment: No.  The expression on the right hand side of an assignment can't know what the target of the assignment is.

Comment: @BrenBarn sure it can! http://stackoverflow.com/a/17601937/432913

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there's not, sorry. I've wished for something like that many times myself.

Comment: Heh, is there any sort of open forum to suggest new features to the language?

Comment: @Subbarker Suggestions can go to the python-ideas mailing list, but you better have (1) several strong use cases, and (2) a concrete, good (this has many dimensions and is somewhat subjective) and otherwise non-objectionable syntax.

Comment: what's wrong with my answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/17601937/432913)? other than it being utterly horrible.   ?

Comment: Well, it kinda misses the whole "save you typing" thing, which is the whole point of something like that.

Answer (score 1):

So you can do this, kind of. It's a filthy hack though...

```
import inspect, sys

def getVariableAtBeginningOfLine():
    lineNumber = inspect.currentframe().f_back.f_lineno
    with open(sys.argv[0]) as f:
        lines = f.read().split("\n")

    #now we have the line we call the function on. 
    line = lines[lineNumber-1]

    #do whatever we want with the line, in this case take the variable at the beginning of the line.
    return eval(line.split()[0])

x = 10

print x #10

x = getVariableAtBeginningOfLine() + 1

print x #11
```

Comment: @Subbarker I'm not sure if i like it though, or think it's too disgusting to be liked.